# Oracle SQL: Find max overlap

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm looking for a way to find the maximum concurrent capacity of an institution (hospital) in terms of the number of studies it can run parallelly.

Even if there is 1 day overlap, the studies are considered to be overlapping. In the below data, there are 2 batches of overlaps at hospital "I1"- in the first batch there are 4 studies overlapping and in the second there are 2 studies overlapping. In summary, the maximum concurrent capacity of I1 is 4 (meaning it can handle 4 studies parallelly).

Can you help/guide with a efficient SQL for this?

Script to create test data is available below. Note: INST_ID is the hospital id.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_INST_DT(INST_ID VARCHAR2(10), STUDY_ID VARCHAR2(10), STUDY_START_DATE DATE, STUDY_END_DATE DATE);

-- Overlap (4 studies)
INSERT INTO TEST_INST_DT VALUES('I1', 'S1', TO_DATE('31-DEC-2021', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), TO_DATE('02-JAN-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO TEST_INST_DT VALUES('I1', 'S2', TO_DATE('01-JAN-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), TO_DATE('05-JAN-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO TEST_INST_DT VALUES('I1', 'S3', TO_DATE('02-JAN-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), TO_DATE('03-JAN-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO TEST_INST_DT VALUES('I1', 'S4', TO_DATE('04-JAN-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), TO_DATE('10-JAN-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'));

-- Overlap (2 studies)
INSERT INTO TEST_INST_DT VALUES('I1', 'S5', TO_DATE('01-FEB-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), TO_DATE('05-FEB-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO TEST_INST_DT VALUES('I1', 'S6', TO_DATE('02-FEB-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), TO_DATE('03-FEB-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'));
```

Comment: How are there 4 overlaps for the first set of 4 studies? The first study finishes on 2022-01-02 and the 3rd study starts at the instant the 1st finishes and the 4th starts after the 1st and 3rd both finish.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the INSERT. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, didn't pay attention to 11g criteria, then try

```
with rtest_inst_dt(rn, inst_id,study_id,study_start_date,study_end_date) as (
    select row_number() over(partition by inst_id order by study_start_date,study_end_date),
        inst_id,study_id, study_start_date,study_end_date
    from test_inst_dt
)
,cte(rn, root, inst_id,study_id,study_start_date,study_end_date) as (
    
    select rn, rn, inst_id,study_id,study_start_date,study_end_date
    from rtest_inst_dt d1
    where not exists(
        select 1 from rtest_inst_dt d2
        where d2.rn < d1.rn and 
        (
            d2.study_end_date between d1.study_start_date and d1.study_end_date 
            or d2.study_start_date between d1.study_start_date and d1.study_end_date 
            or (d2.study_start_date < d1.study_start_date and d2.study_end_date > d1.study_end_date)
        )
    )
    
    union all
    
    select d1.rn, c.root, d1.inst_id, d1.study_id, least(c.study_start_date, d1.study_start_date),
        greatest(c.study_end_date, d1.study_end_date)
    from cte c
    join rtest_inst_dt d1 on d1.rn > c.rn 
        and d1.study_start_date between c.study_start_date and c.study_end_date
)
select inst_id, min(study_start_date) as study_start_date, max(study_end_date) as study_end_date, count(distinct rn) as n 
from cte
group by inst_id, root
;

I1  31/12/21    10/01/22    4
I1  01/02/22    05/02/22    2
```

Answer (score 1):

With MATCH_RECOGNIZE

```
select * from test_inst_dt
match_recognize (
    partition by inst_id
    order by study_start_date, study_end_date
    measures first(study_start_date) as study_start_date, max(study_end_date) as study_end_date, count(*) as nstudies
    pattern( merged* strt )
    define
        merged as max(study_end_date) > next(study_start_date)
);
```

Comment: Oracle 11g does not support `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```sql
SELECT  INST_ID, To_Char(CONCURRENCY, 'MON-yyyy') "CONCURRENCY_MONTH",
        MIN(STUDY_START_DATE) "START_DATE", MAX(STUDY_END_DATE) "END_DATE", COUNT(CONCURRENCY) "CONCURRENCY_COUNT"
FROM ( SELECT  INST_ID, STUDY_ID, STUDY_START_DATE, STUDY_END_DATE,
              Nvl(  CASE  WHEN  INST_ID = PREV_INST_ID And STUDY_START_DATE Between PREV_START_DATE And  PREV_END_DATE 
                          THEN  LEAST(STUDY_END_DATE, PREV_END_DATE)
                        WHEN  INST_ID = PREV_INST_ID And NEXT_START_DATE Between STUDY_START_DATE And STUDY_END_DATE
                          THEN  Nvl(NEXT_END_DATE, STUDY_END_DATE)
                        WHEN  INST_ID = NEXT_INST_ID And STUDY_END_DATE Between NEXT_START_DATE And NEXT_END_DATE
                          THEN  LEAST(NEXT_END_DATE, STUDY_END_DATE)
                        WHEN INST_ID = NEXT_INST_ID And STUDY_START_DATE Between PREV_START_DATE And PREV_END_DATE
                          THEN  LEAST(NEXT_END_DATE, STUDY_END_DATE)
                    END,
                    CASE WHEN STUDY_START_DATE Between MIN(CASE WHEN INST_ID = PREV_INST_ID THEN STUDY_START_DATE END) OVER(Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) And 
                                                       MAX(CASE WHEN INST_ID = PREV_INST_ID THEN STUDY_END_DATE END) OVER(Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row)
                           THEN MAX(CASE WHEN INST_ID = PREV_INST_ID THEN STUDY_END_DATE END) OVER(Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row)
                    END
                  ) "CONCURRENCY"
        FROM    ( Select  INST_ID, LAG(INST_ID) OVER(Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID) "PREV_INST_ID", LEAD(INST_ID) OVER(Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID) "NEXT_INST_ID",
                          STUDY_ID, LAG(STUDY_START_DATE) OVER(Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID) "PREV_START_DATE", STUDY_START_DATE, LEAD(STUDY_START_DATE) OVER(Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID) "NEXT_START_DATE",
                          LAG(STUDY_END_DATE) OVER(Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID) "PREV_END_DATE", STUDY_END_DATE, LEAD(STUDY_END_DATE) OVER(Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID) "NEXT_END_DATE"
                  From    TEST_INST_DT
                  Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID
                )
      ORDER BY INST_ID, STUDY_ID
    )
GROUP BY INST_ID, To_Char(CONCURRENCY, 'MON-yyyy')
```

Which, with your sample data, results as:

| INST_ID | CONCURRENCY_MONTH | START_DATE | END_DATE | CONCURRENCY_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I1 | JAN-2022 | 31-DEC-21 | 10-JAN-22 | 4 |
| I1 | FEB-2022 | 01-FEB-22 | 05-FEB-22 | 2 |

Here the innermost query collects previous and next row's data into every row:

```sql
Select  INST_ID, LAG(INST_ID) OVER(Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID) "PREV_INST_ID", LEAD(INST_ID) OVER(Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID) "NEXT_INST_ID",
                          STUDY_ID, LAG(STUDY_START_DATE) OVER(Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID) "PREV_START_DATE", STUDY_START_DATE, LEAD(STUDY_START_DATE) OVER(Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID) "NEXT_START_DATE",
                          LAG(STUDY_END_DATE) OVER(Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID) "PREV_END_DATE", STUDY_END_DATE, LEAD(STUDY_END_DATE) OVER(Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID) "NEXT_END_DATE"
                  From    TEST_INST_DT
                  Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID

INST_ID    PREV_INST_ID NEXT_INST_ID STUDY_ID   PREV_START_DATE STUDY_START_DATE NEXT_START_DATE PREV_END_DATE STUDY_END_DATE NEXT_END_DATE
---------- ------------ ------------ ---------- --------------- ---------------- --------------- ------------- -------------- -------------
I1                      I1           S1                         31-DEC-21        01-JAN-22                     02-JAN-22      05-JAN-22     
I1         I1           I1           S2         31-DEC-21       01-JAN-22        02-JAN-22       02-JAN-22     05-JAN-22      03-JAN-22     
I1         I1           I1           S3         01-JAN-22       02-JAN-22        04-JAN-22       05-JAN-22     03-JAN-22      10-JAN-22     
I1         I1           I1           S4         02-JAN-22       04-JAN-22        01-FEB-22       03-JAN-22     10-JAN-22      05-FEB-22     
I1         I1           I1           S5         04-JAN-22       01-FEB-22        02-FEB-22       10-JAN-22     05-FEB-22      03-FEB-22     
I1         I1                        S6         01-FEB-22       02-FEB-22                        05-FEB-22     03-FEB-22
```

... it's resulting dataset is transformed with another query ...

```sql
SELECT  INST_ID, STUDY_ID, STUDY_START_DATE, STUDY_END_DATE,
              Nvl(  CASE  WHEN  INST_ID = PREV_INST_ID And STUDY_START_DATE Between PREV_START_DATE And  PREV_END_DATE 
                          THEN  LEAST(STUDY_END_DATE, PREV_END_DATE)
                        WHEN  INST_ID = PREV_INST_ID And NEXT_START_DATE Between STUDY_START_DATE And STUDY_END_DATE
                          THEN  Nvl(NEXT_END_DATE, STUDY_END_DATE)
                        WHEN  INST_ID = NEXT_INST_ID And STUDY_END_DATE Between NEXT_START_DATE And NEXT_END_DATE
                          THEN  LEAST(NEXT_END_DATE, STUDY_END_DATE)
                        WHEN INST_ID = NEXT_INST_ID And STUDY_START_DATE Between PREV_START_DATE And PREV_END_DATE
                          THEN  LEAST(NEXT_END_DATE, STUDY_END_DATE)
                    END,
                    CASE WHEN STUDY_START_DATE Between MIN(CASE WHEN INST_ID = PREV_INST_ID THEN STUDY_START_DATE END) OVER(Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) And 
                                                       MAX(CASE WHEN INST_ID = PREV_INST_ID THEN STUDY_END_DATE END) OVER(Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row)
                           THEN MAX(CASE WHEN INST_ID = PREV_INST_ID THEN STUDY_END_DATE END) OVER(Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row)
                    END
                  ) "CONCURRENCY"
        FROM    ( Select  INST_ID, LAG(INST_ID) OVER(Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID) "PREV_INST_ID", LEAD(INST_ID) OVER(Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID) "NEXT_INST_ID",
                          STUDY_ID, LAG(STUDY_START_DATE) OVER(Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID) "PREV_START_DATE", STUDY_START_DATE, LEAD(STUDY_START_DATE) OVER(Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID) "NEXT_START_DATE",
                          LAG(STUDY_END_DATE) OVER(Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID) "PREV_END_DATE", STUDY_END_DATE, LEAD(STUDY_END_DATE) OVER(Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID) "NEXT_END_DATE"
                  From    TEST_INST_DT
                  Order By INST_ID, STUDY_ID
                )
      ORDER BY INST_ID, STUDY_ID

INST_ID    STUDY_ID   STUDY_START_DATE STUDY_END_DATE CONCURRENCY
---------- ---------- ---------------- -------------- -----------
I1         S1         31-DEC-21        02-JAN-22      02-JAN-22   
I1         S2         01-JAN-22        05-JAN-22      02-JAN-22   
I1         S3         02-JAN-22        03-JAN-22      03-JAN-22   
I1         S4         04-JAN-22        10-JAN-22      10-JAN-22   
I1         S5         01-FEB-22        05-FEB-22      03-FEB-22   
I1         S6         02-FEB-22        03-FEB-22      03-FEB-22
```

... and this is aggregated and grouped by like already shown above.